# toString : when does it return ClassName@HexValue, String Value associated with it

Tags: java, tostring

As per definition `toString()` returns "Returns a string representation of the object as:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

But sometimes I could see even if it is not Overriden in our class, it returns the String associated with it. I mean `Object.toString()` returns some String but not "`ClassName@HexCode`".

When does this happen. Please let me know whats the reason behind this ??

Comment: No, that won't happen unless `toString` is overridden. Please post a short but complete example if you believe you have found a case where that happens. Don't forget that it could be overridden in a subclass of the class you're looking at.

Comment: public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List arg0, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected)
 {
  value.toString()); - Its giving the Value.
 }

Comment: That's not a short but complete example, is it? Please edit into your question (rather than adding as a comment) a complete program demonstrating what's goign on. We have *no context* from just that snippet.

Comment: This is overridden method for ListCellRenderer

Comment: Again, that doesn't give us the context. In particular we have no idea what the execution-time type of the object that `value` refers to is. Just because it's *declared* as `Object` doesn't mean that it's just a plain `Object`. (Look at `value.getClass()` to see what it really is...)

Comment: as far as i know , toString might be overridden , or else not possible

Answer (score 4):

It's only possible if a class extends another class with overriden (or inherited overriden) toString().

Comment: +1: I'd add "directly or inderectly." I think that in your case you just did not see `toString()` in your class because it is written in on of its parents.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of `toString()` is to return the object as

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()).
```

But if you override `toString()` in base class or child class you can specify the way your object should be printed.

Probably in your case its using the inherited method of your base class .

Ex:

```
class Person {
    private String myName; // name of the person
    private int myAge; // person's age
    private String myGender; // 'M' for male, 'F' for female

    // constructor
    public Person(String name, int age, String gender) {
        myName = name;
        myAge = age;
        myGender = gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return myName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return myAge;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return myGender;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        myName = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        myAge = age;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        myGender = gender;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return myName + ", age: " + myAge + ", gender: " + myGender;
    }
 }
 public class Teacher extends Person {
 //...
 }

 calling `toString();` method will call inherited `tOString()` method of base class and will return `return myName + ", age: " + myAge + ", gender: " + myGender;`
```