# trouble with setTime method

Tags: java

Hey guys so I need help with my setTime method. Basically this is the question in my assignment:

Consider a class Time that represents a time of day. It has attributes for the
hour and minute. The hour value ranges from 0 to 23, where the range 0 to
11 represents a time before noon. The minute value ranges from 0 to 59.
a. Write a default constructor that initializes the time to 0 hours, 0 minutes.
b. Write a private method isValid(hour, minute) that returns true if the
given hour and minute values are in the appropriate range.
c. Write a method setTime(hour, minute) that sets the time if the given
values are valid.

I need help with c, in my code you can see that i have the set time method but when i run my programs and enter the time it returns this instead of the numbers in entered:

```
Please enter the hour
3
Please enter the minute
23
The time is time.Time@4d546e25 time.Time@620b66cc
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

My code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package time;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Time {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

//default constructor

public static int hour;
public static int minute;


public Time(){
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;

}


 private static boolean isValid(int hour, int minute)
 //returns true if given hour & minute values are in range
 {
    if((hour >= 0 && hour <= 23) && (minute >= 0 && minute <=11))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
 }


public void setTime(int hour, int minute)
 //set time if given values are valid - 
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the hour");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

    Time.hour = num1;
    System.out.println("Please enter the minute");
    int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    Time.minute = num2;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Karamullah Agha

    Time hour = new Time();
    Time minute = new Time();

    hour.setTime(0,0);


    System.out.println("The time is " + hour + " " + minute);     

  }
}
```

Comment: Please post exact error you are seeing

Answer (score 2):

Your method is re-declaring the variables (but without types), which would shadow the class fields.

```
private boolean isValid(hour, minute)
```

should be something like

```
private boolean isValid()
```

To use the `this.hour` and `this.minute`. **or** to pass them to the method like

```
private boolean isValid(int hour, int minute)
```

Comment: Okay thanks that seems to work. And sorry the error was <identifier> expected private boolean isValid(hour, minute) when i compiled.

Comment: Also if i add the int in front of the hour and minute then public time would have no purpose. This is the question from my assignment: Consider a class Time that represents a time of day. It has attributes for the
hour and minute. The hour value ranges from 0 to 23, where the range 0 to
11 represents a time before noon. The minute value ranges from 0 to 59.
a. Write a default constructor that initializes the time to 0 hours, 0 minutes.
b. Write a private method isValid(hour, minute) that returns true if the
given hour and minute values are in the appropriate range.

Comment: As written, the public `hour` and `minute` have no purpose in the private method. The assignment asks you to [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) them.

Comment: Hey can you help me with the above question? thanks. I changed the question.

Comment: Override `toString` in `Time`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18593043/2970947).